# Dimensions for Mac app?

Tags: macos

I've developed some iPhone apps before, but I focus mostly on design. When designing in Photoshop, the dimensions are easy for the iPhone: 320x480 and 640x960. However, I'm trying to find documentation on dimensions for Mac AppStore. I'm not sure if there are any dimension requirements, since there are many different Mac screen sizes. What guidelines should I follow for designing? Any resources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless there's a really good reason for your app to work at a single size, you should make it resizeable. You should make sure that it at least works well on a screen size as small as 1440x900, and making it fit on the 11" MacBook Air's 1366x768 screen shouldn't be too hard for most apps. If your app is likely to be used in a multitasking scenario, you should make sure that it works with less than half the width of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's [Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGMOSXEnvironment/XHIGMOSXEnvironment.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002721-TPXREF101) specify that Mac OS X supports screens with resolution as low as 800 x 600 pixels. It also says that the display could be rotated for a minimum of 600 x 800 instead. Their advice is to optimize your application for 1024 x 768 pixels, but be resizable for any situation possible.